# chrome.tabs.executeScript|insertCss срабатывает через раз

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, style

Добавляю стили и скрипты на определенный сайт в `background`.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        console.log(tabId, changeInfo, tab);
        if(changeInfo.status === 'complete' && siteUrl.test(tab.url)) {
            insertCss(tab.id, '/css/bootstrap.min.css', function () {
                insertCss(tab.id, '/css/jquery.toast.min.css', function () {
                    insertCss(tab.id, '/css/content_style.css', function () {
                        executeScript(tab.id, '/js/utils/jquery-3.3.1.js', function () {
                            executeScript(tab.id, '/js/utils/js.cookie.js', function () {
                                executeScript(tab.id, '/js/utils/jquery.toast.min.js', function () {
                                    executeScript(tab.id, '/js/utils/sweetalert2.js', function () {
                                        executeScript(tab.id, '/js/core.js', function () {
                                            executeScript(tab.id, '/js/content_script.js', function () {
                                                console.warn('FILES INJECTION COMPLETE');
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Когда заходишь на страницу все нормально инжектится, но если потом обновлять страницу стили и скрипты вставляются через раз - то бишь один раз обновляем ничего нет, еще раз обновляем все появляется.

почему так?

Если писать в `manifest.json` `content_scripts` то тоже не всегда срабатывает. Бывает открывает страницу (не перезагружаешь) и ничего не грузится.

Comment: Я ни разу расширения для хром не делал. Мне вот интересно, обязательно каждый следующий инжект вставлять в колбек предыдущего инжекта? Как-то выглядит это... Страшненько)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko выглядит да. Но если нужна последовательность скриптов как в обычной html странице то приходится так извращаться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А там нету параметра, указывающего инжекту загружаться синхронно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в доках я не вижу https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Comment: Действительно, нету. А почему бы вам не вставлять скрипты через `manifest.json`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko описал причину в конце сообщения главного.

Comment: Загадка... Будем ждать разбирающегося человека, очень интересно будет ответ узнать.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю все необходимые скрипты и стили грузятся локально, т.е. из дирректории расширения. В этом случае рекомендую собрать необходимые бандлы заранее и в правильном порядке, тогда у вас на выходе будет один CSS-файл и один JS. 

Современные инструменты позволяют это выполнять автоматически при каждой сборке проекта.
Это уменьшит вероятность ошибки и гарантирует всегда правильный порядок.

Как верно заметил Stepan Kasyanenko, более верный способ использовать manifest.json для подобной задачи.

От себя добавлю: обратите внимание на директиву [`run_at`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) которая позволяет правильно определить время инжекта вашего кода на страницу.

Comment: про manifest я описал как бы. С подходом инжекта этой проблемы нет. 
Вероятность ошибки может и уменьшит, но увеличит время на поиск бага, если таковой будет. `run_at` знаю и использую. `executeScript` моя функция обертка.

Comment: Ну технически ошибок не вижу. Еще есть вероятность что имеет место быть конфликт между расширением и кодом страницы, хотя это должен быть очень интересный случай.

Comment: @Tsyklop А каким образом вы проверяете что код подключился удачно? На странице появляется какой-то UI?

Comment: Интересная логика у хрома тогда получается. Сейчас я покажу, а вот сейчас нет. Если бы был конфликт то я бы это увидел раньше и т.д.

В консоли выводиться сообщение о том что контент был загружен. Ну и потом появляется UI.

Comment: @Tsyklop, да нет, просто бывают случае, когда event-loop исполняет события страницы и extensions в разном порядке, в зависимости что первое упало в стек вызовов. 
Например: если вы ожидаете события `DOMContentLoaded` и после это производите свои действия на странице, то в некоторых случаях ваш код инджектится после отработки события на странице, таким образом обработчик никогда не срабатывает. Но, обычно, это касается `document_idle`. В вашем случае без полного кода, к сожалению, кроме советов не могу ничего сказать. Прямой ошибки не вижу.

Comment: Прямой ошибки то и нет. просто не исполняется скрипт. я запускаю скрипты с `document_start`.

Comment: @Tsyklop сможете выложить куда-нибудь полный пример проекта?

Comment: Полный к сожалению не могу. подумаю как можно решить. инжект полностью решил мою проблему в принципе.